How to show rows that has null value
So i have this code
WITH gaji_kat AS (
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN income < 20000 THEN 'Gaji Rendah'
        WHEN income > 50000 then 'Gaji Tinggi'
        ELSE 'Gaji Rata-rata'
    END category
FROM accounts)

SELECT
    category,
    COUNT(category)
FROM gaji_kat
group by 1

And the result is this
enter image description here
I wanna show category that has null value. Help me!

Maybe use OR IS NULL?

Your CASE expression can never return NULL.  Please add sample data to your question.

"I wanna show category that has null value." -> There is no category column. That's an alias you defined to a CASE. What do you expect to be null? The income column? Give more context, show the DDL of the tables so we can see the PK, constraints of the table etc. Maybe the income can never be null, for example.

If you wanted to see a fourth category, where the income doesn't fall into the other three because it's null, then remove the else.
It's catching not only the incomes that didn't fall into the first two ranges, but it's also catching your null incomes. Define your ranges explicitly, and the null values will pop up on their own as a fourth group of unhandled cases. Demo at db<>fiddle:
create table accounts(income) as values
(19000),(20000),(21000),(49000),(50000),(51000),(null),(null);

SELECT CASE WHEN income < 20000 THEN 'Gaji Rendah'
            WHEN income > 50000 THEN 'Gaji Tinggi'
            WHEN income >= 20000 
             AND income <= 50000 THEN 'Gaji Rata-rata'
       END AS category,
       COUNT(*)
FROM accounts
GROUP BY 1;




category
count




null
2


Gaji Rendah
1


Gaji Tinggi
1


Gaji Rata-rata
4



If you're only counting rows falling into these categories, you don't need to also select * in the CTE, and you don't actually need the CTE. You also need to replace COUNT(category) with COUNT(*), otherwise the rows where category is null, won't be counted by the function:

count ( * ) → bigint
Computes the number of input rows.


count ( "any" ) → bigint
Computes the number of input rows in which the input value is not null.

